# Rate & Review action?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, hypernyms

What do we call the action of **rating** (with stars) and **reviewing** (commenting) together?

Comment: As on Amazon?  IMDB?  Suggest you give examples of where this applies.  I'm stumped, don't think there is one.  Good question though.

Comment: “Giving a starred review”?

Comment: I have an mobile application , and i want to ask the user to (Rate & review) something , so i want to know in one word what we call this two action in one word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my mind this is still a review.

Rating something with stars can be part of a review. In fact, it is a very brief review in and of itself.

When you want send someone to both rate with stars and review in words, just use the word *review*.

Your form will do the rest of the talking for you.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that came to mind was: Score

from m&w:

```
transitive verb
 5 :  to determine the merit of :  grade
```